# Unable to 'Sign In' or 'Sign Up' with authentication features (no Devise gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am currently unable to Sign Up or Sign In a user through my application and I'm unable to figure out why. I am using nested parameters with my User/Profile models.

When I try to sign up a new user, I get proper flash message saying
"Invalid email or password".

I created my authentication from scratch (**not using Devise!**). I also have a 'forgot password'/'remember me' feature but I have not displayed that information below as I think it is irrelevant.

Here is the **console** log (it seems to be a rollback, but no specific error given):

{`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Ek4cgnR3FQePCg/A4Wqc3atinU+WwRNgj+5hpXsd4mY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"sign@up.co", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"101001010", "last_name"=>"10101110101", "linkedin"=>"www.linkedin.com/signup", "twitter"=>"www.twitter.com/signup"}}, "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."email" = 'sign@up.co' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered users/new.html.haml within layouts/application (60.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 158ms (Views: 75.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)`}

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
delegate :full_name, to: :profile

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
VALID_URL_REGEX   = /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]     {1,5})?(\/.*)?$/ix

validates :email,      :uniqueness => true, :presence => true 
validates :first_name, :presence => true, length: {minimum: 1}
validates :last_name,  :presence => true, length: {minimum: 1}  
validates :twitter,    :format => { with: VALID_URL_REGEX, :multiline => true}
validates :linkedin,   :format => { with: VALID_URL_REGEX, :multiline => true}
```

**models/profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def full_name
    if first_name || last_name
      "#{first_name} #{last_name}".squeeze(" ").strip
    end
  end
end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_profile
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_attributes)
    if @user.save && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id 
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thanks for signing in"

    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def user_attributes
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, 
      :password_confirmation, 
     {profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :linkedin, :twitter]})   
    end

end
```

**controllers/profiles_controller.rb**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_profile

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      redirect_to posts_path
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :linkedin, :twitter)
  end

  def find_profile
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end

end
```

**controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    respond_to do |format|
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        if params[:remember_me]
          cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        else
          cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
        end
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "You're logged in!" }
        format.js do
          flash.now.notice = "You're signed in!"
          render
        end
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

Here are the views (haml)

**views/user/new.html.haml**

```
%h1 Sign Up for a New Account
= simple_form_for @user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  .well
    .container
      = f.input :email, html_input: {class: "form-control"}
      = f.input :password
      = f.input :password_confirmation
      = f.fields_for :profile do |p|
        = p.input :first_name
        = p.input :last_name
        = p.input :linkedin
        = p.input :twitter
        = label_tag :remember_me
        = check_box_tag :remember_me, 1, params[:remember_me]
      = f.submit "Sign Up", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

**views/sessions/new.html.haml

```
%h1 Sign In
= simple_form_for "", url: sessions_path, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.submit "Sign In", class: "btn btn-primary"
%br
%p
  =link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_reset_path
%p  
  No account, yet?
  = link_to "Sign up", signup_path
```

This problem has been bugging me for quite some time. I'd like to test out some of the user functionality but I cannot do so as I'm unable to login. Right now there is only one User record in the database and I created that manually in console. I am not able to log in to that user record either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_attributes)
    if @user.save && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id 
    ...
  end
```

In this code you create an instance variable (`@user`), but you call `authenticate` on `user`. You should either use `User.authenticate` or `@user.authenticate` (depending on how you implemented the `authenticate` method in your model). You should also change `session[:user_id] = user.id` to `session[:user_id] = @user.id`.